# Location background service not working in Swift2

Tags: swift2

I have some odd behaviour in my app.

In my app delegate file I ask the user for permission to use their location while they use the app. This works fine and I can get their current location. After I get their initial location I stop updating location. Great. There is a button users can tap to start updating locations.

If the app is in the foreground I can see that locations are being added to my dictionary every second (I will change this to distanceFilter 10 later). If the user puts the app in to the background location services stop and I don't see the blue bar at the top of the screen.

I have:

- Background modes for location updates enabled
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription set (I am able to successfully ask the user for permission)
- Started the location updates with startUpdatingLocation()
- Tried setting the app to track location always (same result)
- Deleted the app from my phone and reinstalled

In the previous version of my app (before Swift 2) this was working perfectly. I could see location being tracked even when the app was in the background.

I am testing on my iPhone not the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else has the same issue, I had updated my iPhone to iOS9 so it was required for me to add

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdate = true
```

to my location manager.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, please note allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates is plural.

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```